# Based on common usage in print, is it time to accept 'as such' to mean 'therefore'?

Tags: grammar

In published academic writing, I now see *'As such,...'* used so frequently to mean *'Therefore,...'* or *'Consequently,...'* that it leads me to believe that it is time to stop seeing this as 'vulgar' or 'colloquial' and to accept it as common usage.

I have noted that online discussions around a decade ago were already grudgingly leaning towards this conclusion based on usage.

In 2022, is this incorrect usage gaining more ground? Or is it still discarded as incorrect?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133862/discussion-on-question-by-user445639-based-on-common-usage-in-print-is-it-time).

Answer (score 1):

The OED records the informal usage of *as such* (under the entry for *such*)  meaning *accordingly* or *consequently*, which comes very close to *therefore*.

**as such**

> The sense ‘in that capacity’ passes contextually into: **Accordingly**,
> **consequently**, thereupon. *colloquial* or *informal*.
>
> 1800   J. King in *Corr. W. Fowler* (1907) 33   I very much longed to
> hear from you..and **as such** I did not the least esteem it for its
> having been delayed for the reasons assigned.
>
> 1814   W. Fowler in *Corr. W. Fowler* (1907) 297   H. R. H. Princess
> Augusta..motioned for me to come to her Highness. **As such** she
> addressed me in the most pleasant manner possible. (OED)

Here is one example (in context) cited by the OP in a comment below:

> Inspiration is the other reason that this project matters. R. Shanea
> Williams, multiaward-winning director of of *Paralysis (2015),
> explains, "If you don't see yourself often represented in something,
> it's hard to see yourself as a creator of that very thing." **As
> such**, unearthing these invisible histories can have a positive
> impact on future generations of women genre filmmakers. [Alison
> Peirse; *Women Make Horror: Filmmaking, Feminism, Genre*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Women_Make_Horror/bWn9DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=As%20such,%20unearthing%20these%20invisible%20histories%20can%20have%20a%20positive%20impact%20on%20future%20generations%20of%20women%20genre%20filmmakers.&pg=PT34&printsec=frontcover) (2020)

*As such* here creates confusion, at least for me. If I had come across this passage before seeing your question, I'd be looking back, wondering why I couldn't find what "as such" refers to. I see no reason to prefer it over *therefore*. Personally, I would omit it and use a tentative *could* in place of *can* if, as I understand it, this statement is a proposal rather than a finding: "Unearthing these invisible histories could have a positive impact on future generations of women genre filmmakers."

Comment: Yes. I just wonder if it is time to promote this usage from 'colloquial' to be acceptable also in formal, written contexts, given its frequency in published writing these days. I suppose official guidance is always catching up with the actual use of a live language. However, this usage has been markedly on the increase for at least a decade.

Comment: Thanks for engaging in this discussion with me, by the way! There is no 'correct' answer here. I was just curious to learn what fellow language lovers thought about this.

Comment: I suppose this 'as such' is close to 'this being the case'.

Comment: It may be debatable whether the quotations that the OED offers as early examples of such usage really exemplify it: one could argue that they can be read in the way that fits the standard usage of *as such* (as a person who longed to hear from you, as somebody who treats those of lower rank graciously). It would be very hard to come up with such an interpretation of the 2020 example and of the multitude of similar uses of *as such* in the recent literature.

Comment: I agree with @jsw29 The date of the last revision on the OED page is December 2021, but "not fully updated". You would think they could find clearer, contemporary examples for this sense, especially if it is becoming more frequent.